# Stop ScrollView scrolling extending beyond content bounds

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I've got a grouped `GridView` with some explicitly sized databound controls inside it.

The `GridView` has a `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as the `ItemPanelTemplate` type.

As you can see the `ScrollView` scrolls well beyond the content.

Any help appreciated, XAML below.

[image: ScrollView extending beyond content area]

```
<GridView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource contentSetListViewSource}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DashboardContentSetItem}" SelectedIndex="-1" SelectionMode="Multiple" Padding="0,0,0,15" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="20 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>                        
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="0 10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>                
</GridView>
```

Comment: Something you're populating it with is pushing your viewport size, do you know what it might be? Slap a left alignment on your paneltemplate for starters to troubleshoot to push things left and maybe apply a minwidth to make sure it doesnt go further than you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView` by default uses an `ItemsPanelTemplate` consisting of a Border containing a `WrapGrid`.

So I was targeting the wrong panel, this is the fix I used:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

The **reason** being that a WrapGrid isn't variable sized it's fixed to the size of the largest collection, the size of the second grouping (1 item) was the same as the first (5 items) which is why it extended beyond the content.